# Set title after angular promise

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I am trying to learn angular so I have just finished the [heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

I then thought I would have a look at changing this so that I could change the document title per page.  So I followed the instructions to add the [title service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html).

This works all fine and well on my dashboard page where I can simply call the title service in the on init, so I thought I would try adding it to my hero details page to see if I could make the document title be the heroes name:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title }                    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { Hero }                     from '../classes/hero';
import { HeroService }              from '../services/hero.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-details',
    templateUrl: '/app/templates/hero-details.component.template.html'
})

export class HeroDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    hero: Hero;

    constructor(
        private heroService: HeroService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location,
        private titleService: Title
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];

            this.heroService.getHero(id)
                .then(hero => this.hero = hero)
                .then(function () { this.setTitle(this.hero.name); }); // this is the line I have added
        });
    }

    public save(): void {
        this.heroService.update(this.hero)
            .then(() => this.goBack());
    }

    public delete(): void {
        this.heroService
            .delete(this.hero.id)
            .then(() => this.goBack());
    }

    public goBack(): void { 
        console.log('back')
        this.location.back();
    }

    private setTitle(newTitle: string) {
        this.titleService.setTitle(newTitle);
    }
}
```

As you can see from my code, I am trying to set the title after the promise for setting the hero has run.  However, nothing seems to happen - no error is thrown and the title does not change.

What am I doing wrong here?  Would I not chain the promise like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.then(function () { this.setTitle(this.hero.name); });
```

to

```
.then(() => { this.setTitle(this.hero.name); });
```

to retain the scope of `this`

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Wow, so simple when you know! Will accept answer when it lets me